# How to setup localhost Cotrun server for offline development?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, webrtc, turn

I am building a WebRTC project that needs a Coturn server. I am
struggling to setup a localhost version to use for development. Please
do not suggest using a third party TURN server. I have been using them
to this point and have had inconsistent connection and latency issues so
now intend to host one.

The project is using `docker`. The `coturn` image I am using is
https://github.com/kevzettler/coturnDockerLongTermCredentials

I am trying to manually `docker run` the container and get it working.

`docker run \
       --name turnserver \
       --net=host \
       -e "TURN_PORT_START=49152" \
       -e "TURN_PORT_END=65535" \
       -e "TURN_REALM=projectName" \
       -d \
       -t \
       meetrix/coturn-long-term-cred`

To test connections to the turn server I am using
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
and pointing it to `turn:0.0.0.0`

I am able to do this on a production hosting machine and connect successfully using the trickle-ice page. localhost however, is failing.

I want to get a local Coturn setup so I can dev offline. The primary issue I believe is around open PORTS.

Coturn expects a large range of ports open `49152-65535`. If we update
the docker command to explicitly expose these ports like:

`docker run \
       --name turnserver \
       -p 3478:3478/udp \
       -p 3478:3478 \
       -p 49152-65535:49152-65535/udp \
       -e "TURN_PORT_START=49152" \
       -e "TURN_PORT_END=65535" \
       -e "TURN_REALM=projectname" \
       -d \
       -t \
       meetrix/coturn-long-term-cred`

The docker daemon will crash.

This is why the initial run command, and production uses `--net=host`. `--net=host` will
use the host machines firewall instead of `dockers`.

The host machine
for this local dev environment is a macOS Sierra. I suspect the ports
are not open at the macOS level in the `--net=host` scenario.

Comment: any solution from OP?

Answer (score 0):

Remember - docker host network driver is not supported on mac or windows, so it will work only on linux hosts. more details can be found here : https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/

So when doing

```
docker run --rm --network host coturn/coturn:alpine
```

The ports will not be available on localhost.

You will need to explicitly map ports